# Colour change on scroll

Tags: html, jquery, css

Need help replicating a feature on a website (https://www.splinegroup.ca). Would like to replicate the background and font colour change, especially further down from black to white...

Would greatly appreciate any assistance.

Here is what I've tried so far... it's not as smooth
https://codepen.io/laluuk/pen/gOrELGb

Also quite like the way the main text reveals "A Leading Mechanical", would greatly appreciate if someone could help recreating this please.

```js
$(function() {
  $(window).scroll(function() {
    if ($(this).scrollTop() > 150) {
      $('section').removeClass('bg-black', 500)
      //$('section h1').removeClass('text-white')
      $('section').addClass('bg-white', 1000)
    }
    if ($(this).scrollTop() < 150) {
      $('section').removeClass('bg-white', 500)
      $('section').addClass('bg-black', 500)
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.bg-black {
  background-color: #000;
  color: #fff;
}

.bg-white {
  background-color: #fff;
  color: #000;
}

section {
  height: 80vh;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section>
  Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has
  survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing
  software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
</section>
<section>
  Heading
</section>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Explanation :** The changes in `color` and `background` will happen when the value of `cur` will be between 125, and 177 (exclusive). Now, I divided the color in 51 shades (ie same as the difference 176 and 125). For every unit between 125 and 127 (again exclusive), the value of `col` increases/decreases by 5, depending upon the value of `cur`.

You may ask, that what's with 51 shades, and inc/dec in 5. Then the reason is because (5 * 51) = 255 i.e. max possible value of col for `rgb()`.

**NOTE :** Expand it to full screen, while trying out snippet.

```js
var col = 0;

$(window).scroll(function() {
  var cur = $(this).scrollTop();

  if (cur <= 125) {
    col = 0;
  } else if (cur > 125 && cur <= 176) {
    col = (cur - 125) * 5;
  } else {
    col = 255;
  }
  var col2 = 255 - col;

  $('section').css("color", "rgb(" + col + "," + col + "," + col + ")").css("background", "rgb(" + col2 + "," + col2 + "," + col2 + ")")
});
```

```css
section {
  height: 80vh;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section>
  Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has
  survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing
  software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
</section>
<section>
  Heading
</section>
```

Comment: Thanks. 
Still not as smooth as the other website... if you scroll slowly, you will see what I mean...

Comment: @devofash Sorry for earlier, I did not interpret the problem correctly. I have updated the code. Try out and let me know :)

Comment: No worries, ofcourse good old elseif. Could you explain what the "col = (cur - 125) * 5" does? Is x 5 just a random number?

Comment: @devofash Those are not random numbers. You have to calculate first in order to change them. I have added the explanation. Have a look.